# Pivot result with Counts and Sums and show empty cell

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have the following SQL:

```
    SELECT t6.StudentId,
       t6.FirstName,
       t2.Code,
       t2.Title,
       t2.Credit,
       t2.SemesterId
FROM
(
    SELECT t1.*,
           t7.Code,
           t7.Title,
           t7.Credit
    FROM StudentCourses t1
        JOIN CourseOfferings t7
            on t7.Id = t1.CourseOfferingId
    WHERE t1.SemesterId = 63
          AND t1.Status IN ( 'Approved', 'Registered')
) AS t2
    JOIN Students t6
        on t6.StudentId = t2.StudentId
    JOIN StudentCurriculum t3
        on t3.StudentId = t2.StudentId
    JOIN Curriculums t4
        on t4.Id = t3.CurriculumId
    JOIN StudyPrograms t5
        on t5.Id = t4.StudyProgramId
WHERE t5.FacultyId = 2
```

that gives me the following result:

| StudentId | FirstName | Code | Title | Credit | SemesterId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7505 | Toranong | MKTG3204 | Marketing Channels Management and Distribution | 3.0 | 63 |
| 7505 | Toranong | GENL1111 | Health and Wellness | 3.0 | 63 |
| 7505 | Toranong | MNGT2206 | Managing Human Capital | 3.0 | 63 |
| 7505 | Toranong | MKTG3206 | Global Marketing | 3.0 | 63 |
| 7505 | Toranong | MKTG3205 | Integrated Marketing Communication | 3.0 | 63 |
| 7505 | Toranong | GENL1100 | Seminar in Character Dev | 0.0 | 63 |
| 7505 | Toranong | BUAD3305 | English for Career | 3.0 | 63 |
| 7507 | Kannika | GENL1100 | Seminar in Character Dev | 0.0 | 63 |
| 7507 | Kannika | ACCT3213 | Public Sector Accounting | 3.0 | 63 |
| 7507 | Kannika | ACCT3206 | Advanced Accounting II | 3.0 | 63 |
| 7507 | Kannika | ACCT3209 | Internal Audit and Risk Managemen | 3.0 | 63 |
| 7507 | Kannika | ACCT3211 | Cost Management | 3.0 | 63 |
| 7507 | Kannika | BUAD3305 | English for Career | 3.0 | 63 |
| 7510 | Siriporn | ACCT3211 | Cost Management | 3.0 | 63 |
| 7510 | Siriporn | BUAD3305 | English for Career | 3.0 | 63 |
| 7510 | Siriporn | ACCT3206 | Advanced Accounting II | 3.0 | 63 |
| 7510 | Siriporn | ACCT3213 | Public Sector Accounting | 3.0 | 63 |
| 7510 | Siriporn | GENL1100 | Seminar in Character Dev | 0.0 | 63 |
| 7510 | Siriporn | ACCT3209 | Internal Audit and Risk Managemen | 3.0 | 63 |
| 7512 | Aphisit | MKTG3206 | Global Marketing | 3.0 | 63 |
| 7512 | Aphisit | MKTG3205 | Integrated Marketing Communication | 3.0 | 63 |
| 7512 | Aphisit | MNGT2206 | Managing Human Capital | 3.0 | 63 |
| 7512 | Aphisit | GENL1111 | Health and Wellness | 3.0 | 63 |
| 7512 | Aphisit | GENL1100 | Seminar in Character Dev | 0.0 | 63 |
| 7512 | Aphisit | BUAD3305 | English for Career | 3.0 | 63 |
| 7512 | Aphisit | MKTG3204 | Marketing Channels Management and Distribution | 3.0 | 63 |
| 7517 | Pitchaya | GENL1100 | Seminar in Character Dev | 0.0 | 63 |
| 7517 | Pitchaya | ACCT3206 | Advanced Accounting II | 3.0 | 63 |
| 7517 | Pitchaya | ACCT3209 | Internal Audit and Risk Managemen | 3.0 | 63 |

[omitted for brevity][SQL result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRWOx.png)

I want to pivot the result into the following format:

[Click here to view the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZiKs.png)

| ID | Name | BUAD134 Business Communication | BUAD355 International Business | BUAD456 Global Business | ENGL237 Asian Literature | ENGL243 Interpersonal Communication | ENGL251 Public Speaking | ENGL254 Applied Phonetics and Diction | ENGL258 Critical Reading and Thinking | ENGL259 Professional Writing | ENGL341 Social Media Communications | ENGL352 English Grammar | ENGL392 Introductory Res Methods & Writings | HIST212 Intro to Hist. of Western Civilization | IT272 Human-Computer Interaction | IT282 Networking and Data Communications | MATH081 Intermediate Algebra | MKTG232 Principles of Marketing | MUSC111 Introductory Piano Lessons | MUSC121 Introductory Voice Lessons | PSYC115 General Psychology | Total Credits Registered | Number of Courses Registered |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 3 |  |  |
| 7148 | Chanraiya |  |  |  | 3 |  |  | 3 |  | 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 9 | 3 |
| 7149 | Anattanon |  |  |  | 3 | 3 | 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 3 |  |  |  |  | 12 | 4 |
| 7150 | Rotcharat |  | 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 3 |  |  | 3 | 2 |  |  |  | 3 |  |  |  | 14 | 5 |
| 7151 | Sosipho | 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 3 |  | 3 | 3 |  |  |  |  | 3 |  |  |  | 15 | 5 |
| 7152 | Porapat |  |  | 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 3 |  | 3 |  |  |  |  | 3 |  |  | 3 | 15 | 5 |
| 7153 | Zhou |  |  |  | 3 | 3 |  |  | 3 | 3 |  |  |  |  | 3 | 3 |  |  |  |  |  | 18 | 6 |
| 7154 | Su |  |  |  | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 18 | 6 |
| 7155 | Liu |  |  |  | 3 | 3 |  | 3 | 3 | 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 1 |  | 17 | 7 |

The first row is the course credit as you can see it in the image above.
I'm writing the SQL on SQL SERVER 2016 Express.

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at the generation of the pivoted table?

Comment: Honestly, I think that this would be better done in your presentation layer. All *good* reporting layers have the ability the transpose data.